# After adding the MediaRouteButton my App crashes

Tags: android

I have some strange issues:

I added the MediaRouteButton in my Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/group_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/right_btns"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/actionbar_icon_width"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
        android:id="@+id/media_route_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It works really fine on my newer devices. But for older devices with 3.1, 2.3 or lower I'm getting this exception

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #74: Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:671)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
at de.myapp.views.MyActionBar.<init>(MyActionBar.java:54)
... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:416)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:576)
... 43 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01000c a=3}
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1841)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2462)
at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton.<init>(MediaRouteButton.java:121)
at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton.<init>(MediaRouteButton.java:117)    
... 46 more
```

In my code it happens when I inflate the xml Layout

```
public MyActionBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      inflate(context, R.layout.group_action_bar, this);
      titleGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.group_title);
      leftBtnGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.left_btns);
      rightBtnGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.right_btns);
      titleAppendix = findViewById(R.id.group_title_appendix);
   }
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work for older devices with lower api-level?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I could resolved it myself

THe problem is the drawable/list_selector_background.xml

On Pre-ICS devices the selector has a different implementation. I could not reach the code of the support-v7-lib. But settings the background of the MediaRouteButton transparent worked out for me.

```
 <android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
    android:id="@+id/media_route_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: there is a bug in the latest support library (23.1.1) and this no longer works: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192960&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars